# How can I use up to 4 GB ram with Linux 3.0.0+ 32 bit?

Tags: linux

In Windows 32 bit I have the /pae option to use up to 4 GB of RAM for example as a ram disk. Can I configure Linux 32 bit the same way? What option do I need to select in the kernel config menu to enable /pae? When I start top in Linux 32 bit I can only see a total of 2 GB of ram? Does Linux uses up to 4 GB when I install the 64 bit version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install and boot the PAE kernel.  If you are using Red Hat or one of it's derivatives, `yum install kernel-PAE`.

If the RPM doesn't do it for you, you'll want to set the default grub entry to the PAE kernel in `/etc/grub.conf`.

Comment: Is this a kernel module or something? Can I compile it myself?

Comment: It's an actual kernel not a module. There's no need to compile if your distribution already packages the binary. (Unless you have the need to build it with non-default options.)